# Form in Laravel don't send data

Tags: laravel, forms, post

I try to make a form with multiples date inputs, I copy the model from the register / login blade template but it don't work, here is what I do in my template:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('createDispo') }}">
    @csrf

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="date_debut" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Date de début</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="date" name="date_debut" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="date_debut_heure" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Heure de début</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="date" name="date_debut_heure" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="date_fin" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Date de fin</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="date" name="date_fin" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="date_fin_heurev" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Heure de fin</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="date" name="date_fin_heure" class="form-control" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                Ajouter
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

But the form doesn't return a `$data` array like the register or login one, but only the first value (`date_debut` and not in an array, how to properly do a form with Laravel ?

EDIT:

Here is my controller

```
public function createDispo(array $data){
    $disponibilite = new Disponibilite();
    $disponibilite->date_debut = $data["date_debut"];
    $disponibilite->date_fin = $data["date_fin"];
    //$user->disponibilites()->save($disponibilite);
}
```

The problem is that I don't receive this 'data' array but only one value (the first datepicker)

Comment: Hi it's probably related to how you handle the request in your controller, could you post it here?

Comment: I edit my messages

Answer (score 1):

You can access submitted data using the `$request`.  [The docs describe it well](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests).  In your case:

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function createDispo(Request $request){
    $disponibilite = new Disponibilite();
    $disponibilite->date_debut = $request->date_debut;
    $disponibilite->date_fin = $request->date_fin;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you send HTTP requests as this form, the method that should get this information should receive the Illuminate/Http/Request class.

The controller login does that differently because the controller send the $request->all() (this is an array) to the method login after the validation.

So what you have to do, is to change:

```
public function createDispo(array $data){
```

To

```
public function createDispo(Request $data){
```

Or to be more consistent to variables:

```
public function createDispo(Request $request){
```

Then you can access the data with:

```
public function createDispo(Request $request){

    $disponibilite = new Disponibilite();
    $disponibilite->date_debut = $request->date_debut;
    $disponibilite->date_fin = $request->date_fin;
    //$user->disponibilites()->save($disponibilite);
}
```

Remember to import the class of Illuminate\Http\Request when using Request

Comment: That error means that you are making a request with a certain method tha is not registered in your route, for example if in your route file you create the Route::get('create_dispo', .......); you will receive the error because your form is sending the data Via POST and the route is defined as GET